# Node.js, Ajax sending and receiving Json

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, html, node.js

Using Ajax, I'm trying to just send Json data to a node server no processing involved just alerting when it's sent and alerting when it's received:

This is my html5: Simple button with an onclick function to trigger the function to use the ajax call

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function send()
            {
                //alert("Hello World");
                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "http://localhost:8000", 
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                    data:  JSON.stringify({name: "Dennis", address: {city: "Dub", country: "IE"}})
                }).done(function ( data ) {alert("ajax callback response:" + data);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="send()">Click Me!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is a portion of my node server: For creating a server and listening for certain actions

```
var port = 8000;
var server = http.createServer();
server.on('request', request);
server.listen(port);

function request(request, response) 
{
    var store = '';
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/json"});
    request.on('data', function(data) 
    {
        store += data;
    });
    request.on('end', function() 
    {
       store = JSON.parse(store);
        console.log(store); 
        response.end(store);
    });
}
```

No alerts are being fired so I don't think the ajax is attempting to send the information.

Comment: Open your console, do you see any errors?

Comment: Open your developer tools Net tab, do you see the request you expect and the response you expect?

Comment: Why are you telling jQuery to expect JSON when you have a text/plain content type? Why are you sending a 200 response with no response body?

Comment: @Quentin ok i understand I was doing that wrong! now its stating that my send is unreferenced

Comment: Paste your JS into http://jshint.com/ (but I'd have expected that error to show up in the JS console when the document loaded).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this on the server side:

```
var port = 8000;
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer();
server.on('request', request);
server.listen(port);
function request(request, response) {
    var store = '';

    request.on('data', function(data) 
    {
        store += data;
    });
    request.on('end', function() 
    {  console.log(store);
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/json");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.end(store)
    });
 }
```

and this on the client side:

```
$.ajax
({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:8000",
  crossDomain:true, 
  dataType: "json",
  data:JSON.stringify({name: "Dennis", address: {city: "Dub", country: "IE"}})
 }).done(function ( data ) {
      alert("ajax callback response:"+JSON.stringify(data));
   })
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: This example worked thank you! Jus one thing a bracket is missing after "IE"}} it should be "IE"}})

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `response.write()` or `response.end()` with a plain javascript object, you can only write Buffers or strings.

So what you need to do is stringify the object first. Either change the `response.end(store);` to `response.end(JSON.stringify(store));` or don't `store = JSON.parse(store);` in the first place (unless you are doing it to validate the JSON -- and if that was that case you should wrap it in a try-catch because `JSON.parse()` will throw on parse error).