# How to receive a nodejs data response from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I am currently learning express, ajax, and nodejs. So currently I am trying to make ajax and nodejs interact with each other. I am sending a client request, using ajax, to a nodejs server. Currently, I am able to invoke `app.get` in the server correctly, i.e. it works fine until the call to `console.log(req.query);` at the server side. However, I am having trouble accepting data, that is sent by the server. The client side code does not alert any returned data as I tried to make it to.

This is my code on the client side.

```
function login(){
  var obj = '{"username":"'+$('#username').val()+'", "password":"'+$('#password').val()+'"}';
  $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    dataType :'json',
    data:{"username": $("#username").val(),
          "password": $("#password").val()},
    url:'http://localhost:10351/function',
    success: function (data) {
        alert("ajax callaback response:"+JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  })
```

This is my code on the server side.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer();
var portNumber = 10351;
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/function', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.query);
    res.send(JSON.stringify(req.query));
});

app.listen(portNumber, function() {
    console.log('Currently listening on port ' + portNumber);
});
```

Any tips?

I was looking at the answer in the following link:

[Node.js, Ajax sending and receiving Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784614/node-js-ajax-sending-and-recieving-json)

and I thought maybe i could use response.end and response.setHeader instead?
I'm not quite sure if my problem lies on the client side or the server side.

Comment: It appears maybe you wanted to log the response, not the request?  did you try changing your console.log to `console.log(res)` or `res.headersSent` ?  Also you might to set up some error control first to grab any potential failures like this. Ajax failures will just disappear making it real difficult to see whats going on in an async environment.

Answer (score 1):

You don't

1. Listen to the right port (10901 vs 10351)
2. Send any parameters in the query section of the url
3. Need JSON.stringify because you already get a string in `(req.query)`

You should:

1. Make the ports match
2. Send parameters in the url ex:(`url:'http://localhost:10351/function?foo=bar`)
3. Remove the stringify ex:

   `res.send(req.query)`

   `alert("ajax callaback response:"+data);`

`response.end` is not needed if you already use the `res.send` method, and `response.setHeader` would be helpful if you want to mark this content as json, so you can put a `Content-Type: application/json` header,
Or use `res.json` to do both of these things for you (stringify the json and put the right header for you)

Comment: Apologies, i fixed the port issue earlier and it still does not work. Do you mind elaborating a bit on the second point?

Comment: you would still need to see the response, to know whats going on. sans the stringify, just concentrate on the console log until you understand what the actual response is would be my suggestion.

Comment: Edited the answer, look again

Answer (score 0):

Your ports don't match in code. You said your call worked until console.log(), if the ports don't match it won't even enter app.get() in server.
I think you just posted a different code for client.

I will suggest you to try postman which is chrome extension that will be really helpful to send and get ajax request responses. Using you code just by changing the port number I am able to get the response in postman.

Comment: Initially i used port number 10351 on both sides but when i wanted to copy them to stackoverflow i accidentally copied the server side code from an older file i was tweaking with,

Comment: Try opening chrome developer tools and check the response headers under Networks tab.