# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require node.js

Tags: node.js, dependencies

I have tried the related solutions for this problem (eg. add the dependencies through 'package.json' and run npm install) but unfortunately they didn't solve it. Problem is when I run the code from the accepted answer from the following discussion: 
[Node.js, Ajax sending and receiving Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784614/node-js-ajax-sending-and-receiving-json/44965943?noredirect=1#comment76906741_44965943)

everything works fine. the Ajax-call works and I get the result with the data. But in the console I get the error.

```
'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require' (Globale code — requesthandle.js:2ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require)
```

Any ideas which could be the problem here? Thank you!

This is the code I am using:

requesthandle.js (server side, by executing node requesthandle.js) ==>

http://i67.tinypic.com/24zbyma.png

and

list.html (by visiting mydomain/list.html)

http://i65.tinypic.com/mwp3md.png

Comment: are you using require on frontend side javascript?

Comment: Thank you for your fast response; I am using require on the back-end javascript.

Comment: not sure but looks like your node installation is broken. Try to use require on node.js console

Comment: This gives the following output: { [Function: require]
  resolve: [Function],
  main: undefined,
  extensions: { '.js': [Function], '.json': [Function], '.node': [Function] },
  cache: {} }
> require("http")
{ IncomingMessage: 
   { [Function: IncomingMessage]
     super_: 
      { [Function: Readable]
        ReadableState: [Function: ReadableState],
        super_: [Object],
        _fromList: [Function: fromList] } },
  METHODS: 
   [ 'CHECKOUT',
     'CONNECT',
     'COPY',
     'DELETE',
     'GET',
     'HEAD',
     'LOCK',
....
Is this OK?

Comment: then require is working fine. Post your code where you are getting the error. Also post how you are running it. Without code it seems hard to find the problem

Comment: I have added my code to my primary question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.. overlooked the fact I included the requesthandle.js in my list.html / client-side code. Thank you for your help Arpit Solanki! Seems your first remark included the solution: I was using it frontend by mistake..